# stringr::str_locate is not taking variable input

Tags: r

In text mining, I want to clean text after certain words(email signature cleaning) till end. For that I am using  `stringr::str_locate`

with find the location of given text. It's working when I am passing the text one by one. But, when I am passing at one go using loop it's not taking.

**Following is my script:**

```
    library(stringr)
    txt <- c("Hello.\r\ncorrections have been done now.\r\nCheers, Peik Niemi\r\ncheers, Peik\r\n\r\nBest Regards,\r\nAngelo Javier\r\n------------------- Original Message -------------------\r")
    salt <- c("NOTICE:", "Many thanks", "Sincerely", "With gratitude", "rgds", "tks", "cheers","tc", "disclaimer", "kind regards","best regards","thanks and regards","Sent from my","Outlook for Android","[\n\r].*--","warm regards","thanks & regards","regards","\\*\\*")
     names(salt) <- salt[]
             Salute <- function(txt){
              for(i in salt[,]){
                txt1 <- tolower(txt)
                assign(salt1, names(salt[i]))
                # salt1 = salt[i]
                dis_loc = as.data.frame(str_locate(as.character(txt1, pattern=fixed(salt1))))[1,1]
                }
              if(is.na(dis_loc)){ct = txt}
              if(is.na(dis_loc)==F){ct = (substr(txt,1, (dis_loc-1)))}
              substr(txt,1, (dis_loc-1))
              ct <- as.data.table(ct)
              return(ct)
            }

txtClean <- lapply(txt,Salute)
```

**Error:**
*Error in type(pattern) : argument "pattern" is missing, with no default*

**Expected Output:**
*"Dear Murray,
Time for a band meeting"*

Kindly help me with proper way to pass a list in Str_locate.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Following code removes everything occurring after (and including) one of your keywords:

```
str_replace(txt,paste0("(?i)(",paste(salt,collapse="|"),")(?s).*"),"")
#[1] "Dear Murray,\nTime for a band meeting\n"

txt <- "Hello.\r\ncorrections have been done now.\r\nCheers, Peik Niemi\r\ncheers, Peik\r\n\r\nBest Regards,\r\nAngelo Javier\r\n------------------- Original Message -------------------\r"
str_replace(txt,paste0("(?i)(",paste(salt,collapse="|"),")(?s).*"),"")
#[1] "Hello.\r\ncorrections have been done now.\r\n"
```

Comment: It works, however, it deletes valid text also if I put txt = "Hello.\r\ncorrections have been done now.\r\nCheers, Peik Niemi\r\ncheers, Peik\r\n\r\nBest Regards,\r\nAngelo Javier\r\n------------------- Original Message -------------------\r"

Comment: That's because of the `"[\n\r].*--"` rule. I put `(?is)` in my regex to collect several lines in the `.*`. In order to make your rule working, you can change it by : ` "(?-s)[\n\r].*--"`

Comment: Nothing is getting replaced at this time.

Comment: Code:
str_replace(txt1,paste0("(?-s)[\n\r].*--(",paste(salt,collapse="|"),").*"),"")

Comment: Still not working. However, if I remove "[\n\r].*--" and "\\*\\*" and put then separately in str_locate then it works. So, i need 3 functions. One for words in "salt" and other twos for special characters.

Comment: It works for me. Please update your question with a full test case.